# Racket: What does double colon (::) mean?

Tags: python, numpy, lisp, racket

New to Racket, and for some reason can't find this in the official documentation anywhere.  Is the double colon just used in this `(require math/array)` library, or is it generally useful in Racket?

I **do** know I'm trying to do something similar to python's numpy indexing `arr[i:j,k:m] = 1` .  So if there's a less complex way of setting a bunch of values in an array to the same value, please let me know

```
> (define arr (array->mutable-array (axis-index-array #(5 5) 1)))
> (array-slice-set! arr (list (:: 1 #f 2) (::)) (array 1))
> arr

- : (Mutable-Array Integer)

(mutable-array

 #[#[0 1 2 3 4]

   #[1 1 1 1 1]

   #[0 1 2 3 4]

   #[1 1 1 1 1]

   #[0 1 2 3 4]])
> (array-slice-set!
   arr (list (::) (:: 1 #f 2))
   (array-scale (array-slice-ref arr (list (::) (:: 1 #f 2))) -1))
> arr

- : (Mutable-Array Integer)

(mutable-array

 #[#[0 -1 2 -3 4]

   #[1 -1 1 -1 1]

   #[0 -1 2 -3 4]

   #[1 -1 1 -1 1]

   #[0 -1 2 -3 4]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extended example of slicing here:

https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array_slicing.html

Can't find anything that sets a slice to a constant though. 
I went ahead an implemented such a thing see below.

First let's try out some examples.

```
#lang racket
(require math/array)

;;; 1d array

; xc : vector -> integer
;  get first coordinate (the "x coordinate")
(define (xc v) 
  (vector-ref v 0))

;; Build a 1d array with elements 0, 1, ..., 9
(define A
  (array->mutable-array
   (build-array
    #(10)  ; one axis (the x-axis) range 0, 1, ..., 9
    xc)))  ; use index as-is

;; Show the 1d array
A

;; Let's set the middle part to zero.
;; First we make a slice

(:: 4 7)

;; Then we use it to set elements in the arrau

(array-slice-set! A (list (:: 4 7)) (array #[0 0 0]))
A ; now the tree middle elements are 0

;; Rather than write the zero array our-selves we can use make-array.
(array-slice-set! A (list (:: 4 7)) (make-array #(3) 1))
A

;;; nd array

(define (coordinates v) (vector->list v))

(define B
  (array->mutable-array
   (build-array
    #(4 4 4)  ; three axes of size 4
    coordinates)))

B

;;; Let set the all entries except the "edge" ones to (x x x)

(array-slice-set! B (list (:: 1 3) (:: 1 3) (:: 1 3))
                  (make-array (vector (- 3 1) (- 3 1) (- 3 1)) '(x x x)))
B

;;; Now to avoid constructing the constant array, we will use the
;;; array-slice-set-constant! see below.

(require "array-slice-set-constant.rkt")
(array-slice-set-constant! B (list (:: 1 3) (:: 1 3) (:: 1 3)) '(y y y))
B
```

The output is:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.12 [3m].
Language: racket, with debugging.
(mutable-array #[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])
(:: 4 7 1)
(mutable-array #[0 1 2 3 0 0 0 7 8 9])
(mutable-array #[0 1 2 3 1 1 1 7 8 9])
(mutable-array
 #[#[#['(0 0 0) '(0 0 1) '(0 0 2) '(0 0 3)]
     #['(0 1 0) '(0 1 1) '(0 1 2) '(0 1 3)]
     #['(0 2 0) '(0 2 1) '(0 2 2) '(0 2 3)]
     #['(0 3 0) '(0 3 1) '(0 3 2) '(0 3 3)]]
   #[#['(1 0 0) '(1 0 1) '(1 0 2) '(1 0 3)]
     #['(1 1 0) '(1 1 1) '(1 1 2) '(1 1 3)]
     #['(1 2 0) '(1 2 1) '(1 2 2) '(1 2 3)]
     #['(1 3 0) '(1 3 1) '(1 3 2) '(1 3 3)]]
   #[#['(2 0 0) '(2 0 1) '(2 0 2) '(2 0 3)]
     #['(2 1 0) '(2 1 1) '(2 1 2) '(2 1 3)]
     #['(2 2 0) '(2 2 1) '(2 2 2) '(2 2 3)]
     #['(2 3 0) '(2 3 1) '(2 3 2) '(2 3 3)]]
   #[#['(3 0 0) '(3 0 1) '(3 0 2) '(3 0 3)]
     #['(3 1 0) '(3 1 1) '(3 1 2) '(3 1 3)]
     #['(3 2 0) '(3 2 1) '(3 2 2) '(3 2 3)]
     #['(3 3 0) '(3 3 1) '(3 3 2) '(3 3 3)]]])
(mutable-array
 #[#[#['(0 0 0) '(0 0 1) '(0 0 2) '(0 0 3)]
     #['(0 1 0) '(0 1 1) '(0 1 2) '(0 1 3)]
     #['(0 2 0) '(0 2 1) '(0 2 2) '(0 2 3)]
     #['(0 3 0) '(0 3 1) '(0 3 2) '(0 3 3)]]
   #[#['(1 0 0) '(1 0 1) '(1 0 2) '(1 0 3)]
     #['(1 1 0) '(x x x) '(x x x) '(1 1 3)]
     #['(1 2 0) '(x x x) '(x x x) '(1 2 3)]
     #['(1 3 0) '(1 3 1) '(1 3 2) '(1 3 3)]]
   #[#['(2 0 0) '(2 0 1) '(2 0 2) '(2 0 3)]
     #['(2 1 0) '(x x x) '(x x x) '(2 1 3)]
     #['(2 2 0) '(x x x) '(x x x) '(2 2 3)]
     #['(2 3 0) '(2 3 1) '(2 3 2) '(2 3 3)]]
   #[#['(3 0 0) '(3 0 1) '(3 0 2) '(3 0 3)]
     #['(3 1 0) '(3 1 1) '(3 1 2) '(3 1 3)]
     #['(3 2 0) '(3 2 1) '(3 2 2) '(3 2 3)]
     #['(3 3 0) '(3 3 1) '(3 3 2) '(3 3 3)]]])
(mutable-array
 #[#[#['(0 0 0) '(0 0 1) '(0 0 2) '(0 0 3)]
     #['(0 1 0) '(0 1 1) '(0 1 2) '(0 1 3)]
     #['(0 2 0) '(0 2 1) '(0 2 2) '(0 2 3)]
     #['(0 3 0) '(0 3 1) '(0 3 2) '(0 3 3)]]
   #[#['(1 0 0) '(1 0 1) '(1 0 2) '(1 0 3)]
     #['(1 1 0) '(y y y) '(y y y) '(1 1 3)]
     #['(1 2 0) '(y y y) '(y y y) '(1 2 3)]
     #['(1 3 0) '(1 3 1) '(1 3 2) '(1 3 3)]]
   #[#['(2 0 0) '(2 0 1) '(2 0 2) '(2 0 3)]
     #['(2 1 0) '(y y y) '(y y y) '(2 1 3)]
     #['(2 2 0) '(y y y) '(y y y) '(2 2 3)]
     #['(2 3 0) '(2 3 1) '(2 3 2) '(2 3 3)]]
   #[#['(3 0 0) '(3 0 1) '(3 0 2) '(3 0 3)]
     #['(3 1 0) '(3 1 1) '(3 1 2) '(3 1 3)]
     #['(3 2 0) '(3 2 1) '(3 2 2) '(3 2 3)]
     #['(3 3 0) '(3 3 1) '(3 3 2) '(3 3 3)]]])
```

The file "array-slice-set-constant.rkt" contains:

```
#lang typed/racket/base
(provide array-slice-set-constant!)

(require math/private/array/for-each
         math/private/array/array-struct
         math/private/array/typed-array-indexing
         math/private/array/array-constructors
         math/private/array/for-each
         math/private/array/utils)

(: array-indexes-set-constant! (All (A) ((Settable-Array A) (Array In-Indexes) A -> Void)))
(define (array-indexes-set-constant! arr idxs constant)
  (define ds        (array-shape idxs))
  (define idxs-proc (unsafe-array-proc idxs))
  (for-each-array-index ds (λ (js) (array-set! arr (idxs-proc js) constant))))

(: array-slice-set-constant! (All (A) ((Settable-Array A) (Listof Slice-Spec) A -> Void)))
(define (array-slice-set-constant! arr slices val)
  (let ([idxs  (parameterize ([array-strictness #f])
                 (array-slice-ref (indexes-array (array-shape arr)) slices))])
    (array-indexes-set-constant! arr idxs val)))
```

We ought to put that function into the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

`::` [appears to be](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array_slicing.html) a [procedure defined in `math/array`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array_indexing.html#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Farray..rkt%29._~3a~3a%29%29):

> Create [`Slice`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array_indexing.html#%28form._%28%28lib._math%2Farray..rkt%29._.Slice%29%29) objects using [`::`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array_indexing.html#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Farray..rkt%29._~3a~3a%29%29) and [`Slice-New-Axis`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array_indexing.html#%28form._%28%28lib._math%2Farray..rkt%29._.Slice-.New-.Axis%29%29) objects using [`::new`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array_indexing.html#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Farray..rkt%29._~3a~3anew%29%29). There is only one [`Slice-Dots`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array_indexing.html#%28form._%28%28lib._math%2Farray..rkt%29._.Slice-.Dots%29%29) object, namely [`::...`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array_indexing.html#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Farray..rkt%29._~3a~3a......%29%29).

I don't think it's generally applicable to the rest of Racket.